# What Apple stock apps allow exported UTIs?

Tags: ios, ios4, uti

Using [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774343/how-do-i-associate-file-types-with-an-iphone-application), I made it so that my app is able to open jpeg's and pngs by clicking the "Open in (my app)" button.

This works say, when I open a photo in the messages app and click share. But, I can't seem to get it to work anywhere else. My app doesn't pop up in photos, or mail.

So my question is, am I doing something wrong or is messages the only app that supports exporting files? If not, which apps do? Is there a list?

Thanks,
Gabe

Comment: You are doing nothing wrong. For some unknown reason, Apple does not provide the "Open In" option for images in the Mail or Photos app. It's very annoying. File an enhancement request. The more people that do the more likely Apple will fix this shortcoming.

Comment: BTW - why is this tagged with `iphone-sdk-4.0`? Apple doesn't accept apps that support iOS 4.0.

Comment: Is messages the only supported app?

Comment: Messages, Mail, and Photos are the only Apple apps I can think of that work with images and only Messages presents an "Open In" option. My own app can share images and it works with any registered app. Apple made a (bad) choice for Mail and Photos. File the enhancement request to fix this.